# Asynchronous image drawing with OpenTK

Tags: c#, asynchronous, opentk

I got a scene on which I execute some commands. Lets suppose I want to make a simulation and every step of it, I can do sth like that.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    commands[global++].Execute(ref area.heightMap, ref sim);
    glControl1.Invalidate();  //openTK redrawing
}
```

Clicking the button will display every step on scene.
But now I want to see a continous simulation I can do sth like that.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count; i++)
    {
       button4_Click(null, null);
       Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

But the effect is not as I suppose, all commands are executed and then lastly the image displayed. So the question is how do I dispaly every step of this simulation (after every execute command).
Extra question - suppose this Execute() consists of many small steps. How do I display all of this small steps ?

Comment: I managed to do it with background worker. Anyway is it possible to do it with Delegates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must Execute command on another thread (you can use TPL) and wait in working thread, but in UI thread you must only Invalidate control.

```
foreach(var command in commands)
{
    Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteCommand)
        .ContinueWith(
            t => Invalidate(t.Result),
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}


private void Invalidate(int heightMap)
{
    area.heightMap = eightMap;
    glControl1.Invalidate();
}

private int ExecuteCommand()
{
    // returns new heightMap, because it's executes in non-UI thread
    // you can't set UI control property
    return Execute(area.heightMap, sim);
}
```

Comment: I see I can also do it with BackgroundWorker. But this wont solve the issue with getting many results from signle step in Execute command. Is it possible to solve it using some delegates ? I havent used them already

Comment: Does Invalidate use area.heightMap and sim?

Comment: Yes Invalidate use area.heightMap (this heightMap is exactly what I am displaying), sim is not used by Invalidate (sim stands for simulationParameters which affects the result of execute command method).

Comment: To be exact. Single execute command updates height map depending on sim (and command itself) in many steps which should be continously displayed.